# Tableview didSelectRowAt wrongly selects row with JSON data in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to select a tableview row with a checkbox. However, if I select the first cell, then the second cell is selected. If I select the second cell, the third cell is selected, and if I select the third cell, then the first cell is selected. Why is this happening? Can you help me correct this issue?

**Code:**

```swift
extension StudentSignupStep4ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        subscriptionList?.result?.subscriptionData?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SubscriptionTableViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! SubscriptionTableViewCell
        let cellData = subscriptionList?.result?.subscriptionData?[indexPath.row]
        cell.subscriptionNameLabel.text = cellData?.subscription_name
     
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let subscriptionData = subscriptionList?.result?.subscriptionData else { return }
        for i in subscriptionData.indices {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? SubscriptionTableViewCell {
                cell.isChecked = i == indexPath.row
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
        subsciptionId = subscriptionList?.result?.subscriptionData?[indexPath.row].id
    }
}

class SubscriptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var checkboxImageView: UIImageView!
    var isChecked = false {
        didSet {
            checkboxImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: (isChecked) ? "checkmark.square.fill": "square")
            checkboxImageView.tintColor = (isChecked) ? .myAccentColor: .lightGray
        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, you should do "cell.isChecked = ...", and in `didSelect` you iterate over all cells? Why?

Comment: @Larme this was done by other developer now i got code to fix the issues.. i to didn't understand why he does like this... now what will be the solution for this. can u guide

Comment: @Larme generally i dont use like (array.indices)  `subscriptionData.indices` so i am unable to fix the issue now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
    for i in subscriptionData.indices {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? SubscriptionTableViewCell {
            cell.isChecked = i == indexPath.row
        }
    }
```

That is completely wrong. Do not talk to the cells directly in this way, ever. Talk only to the *data model* (`subscriptionList?.result?.subscriptionData`). Then reload the table view, and let `cellForRow` read the data model for the individual index path and configure the cell accordingly (as it is already doing).

And delete the cell's `isChecked` property. A cell is *view*, and a highly volatile view at that (because cells, as you've been told, are reused); a cell must not make any attempt to maintain *state*.